# How to vertical align dt tags in relation to its dd tags?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have this html:

```
<dl>
    <dt><label for='txaText'>Text</label></dt>
    <dd><textarea id='txaText'></textarea></dd>
</dl>
```

and this css:

```
dt {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
  padding-right:5px;
}
dd {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

But I get this:

[image: css1]

And I wanted this:

[image: css2]

How can I achieve this vertical alignment of the dt tag in relation to its respective dd tag? Can I do this without horrible hacks like creating divs or specifying the height in pixels for each label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I came up with a solution that you may like, you can set your elements to `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` to align them.

CSS:

```
dl{
   border: 1px solid red;
}

dt {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 30%;
  padding-right:5px;
}
dd {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Updated [CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/QjVNXw/) for you.

Comment: I have dozens of pages with dozens of dt/dd pairs in each one. I just can't be typing the height in pixels for every pair! As I said, this is a "horrible hack". I would have to readjust everything if I change the default font, for instance, or the default textarea height...

Comment: It's not if it's calculated in relation to it's parent, but there is a wrap way you can aslo do it, which I updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but your second solution has TWO things that I wanted to avoid.

Comment: If there's no direct way to vertical align a dt tag, I prefer to leave it without vertical alignment, instead of creating thousands of divs... But thanks for trying.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to come up with a solution that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Gothburz, but I have more than one textarea. Actually I have some inputs type=text, and some textareas. If I add a button to the side of the textarea or input (still inside the dd), somehow the horizontal alignment (between the dt and dd) is messed up :/ Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, it works. Can't remember why I didn't accept this before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question and wanted to include a flexbox answer for anyone else that finds this. Flexbox makes this task pretty trivial which is great for developers!

```css
dl {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: This puts all the items on the same line.

Answer (score -2):

```
You can try this code.

html code:

<dl>
    <dt><label for='txaText'><br>Text</label></dt>
    <dd><textarea id='txaText'></textarea></dd>
</dl>

and this css code:

dt {
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
  padding-right:5px;
}
dd {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a <BR> is not actually a solution, since different controls have different heights, so the number of <BR> would be variable. Also, this destroys completely the very idea of what "vertical align" means.